# efficient way of searching a character in a set of character C language

Tags: c

I have a set of characters, minimum hundreds of characters. How could i get the position of a  particular character in that list efficiently.

Comment: A set of characters with a minimum of hundreds? Is this a set of strings or just one really long string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert the set into a ordered list and use binary search.

Comment: Ok. even then converting into a list will consume time. Will the time in converting to list will be effective w.r.t speed effectively.

Comment: If there will be multiple search operations based on the set. So it is always no worse than the simple scan.

Answer (score 2):

If you set of characters is sorted, you can use [`bsearch()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch).

If not, you're pretty much out of luck - you'll have to use a simple scan, like [`strchr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr).